# Xamarin, What is the difference between tab page click vs button page click?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

When i click on the tab page () a new settings page comes on but it's not populated with the info i already entered but it i click on a button (Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SettingsPage());) the page comes on and its populated with info I entered. is there a difference between the two?

```
//for tab page
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bldg"
        x:Class="Bldg.HomePage" >

<local:HistoryLogPage Title="Log"/>
<local:AddDrainsPage Title="Add"/>
<local:SettingsPage Title="Edit Settings"/> 

<Label x:Name="drain1Label" />

</TabbedPage>

//for click button
void NextpageButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{ 
Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SettingsPage());
}

//SettingsPage

namespace Bldg
{
public partial class SettingsPage : ContentPage
{

public static string item, username;
public static string location1, location2;
bool is1Empty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.n1LocationSettings);
bool is2Empty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.n2LocationSettings);

List<string> list;

public SettingsPage()
{

InitializeComponent();
drainquantity();

list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("1");
    list.Add("2");

locationPicker1.SelectedIndexChanged += drain1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;
locationPicker2.SelectedIndexChanged += drain2Handle_SelectedIndexChanged;

//nameofpickerinxamlfile.On<iOS().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);


locationPicker1.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);
locationPicker2.On<iOS>().SetUpdateMode(UpdateMode.WhenFinished);

drainxPicker.SelectedItem = Settings.DrainquantitySettings;
locationPicker1.SelectedItem = Settings.n1LocationSettings;
locationPicker2.SelectedItem = Settings.n2LocationSettings;

nameEntry.Text = Settings.NameSettings;

clearButton.IsVisible = false;

drainlocationPicker2.IsEnabled = false;

drainxPicker.SelectedItem = Settings.DrainquantitySettings;
}

//this is fired when user changes or selects new selection
void drainxHandle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
//to get the value of user selected going to be use in switch; then save in a 
variable
var drainx = drainxPicker.Items[drainxPicker.SelectedIndex];

item = (string)drainxPicker.SelectedItem;


bool isdrainxEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Settings.DrainquantitySettings);

if (isdrainxEmpty == true)
{

//switch for user selected in drainpicker

switch (drainx)
{               
case "1":
n1Gridrow.IsVisible = true;
locationPicker1.IsVisible = true;
n2Gridrow.IsVisible = false;

if (is1Empty == true)
{
drainxPicker.IsEnabled = true;
}
else
drainxPicker.IsEnabled = false;

break;

case "2":
n1Gridrow.IsVisible = true;
n2Gridrow.IsVisible = true;
locationPicker2.IsEnabled = false;

break;

}  //switch end
}
else
{
drainxPicker.IsEnabled = false;
nameEntry.IsEnabled = false;
n1Gridrow.IsVisible = true;
n2Gridrow.IsVisible = true;

locationPicker1.IsEnabled = false;
locationPicker2.IsEnabled = false;

settingsaveButton.IsVisible = false;

}

}

void n1Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

location1 = (string)locationPicker1.SelectedItem;
if (is1Empty == true)
{
locationPicker2.IsEnabled = true;
n2Label.IsVisible = true;

locationPicker2.Items.Remove((string)locationPicker1.SelectedItem);
}

drainxPicker.IsEnabled = false;
locationPicker1.IsEnabled = false;

}

void n2Handle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
location2 = (string)locationPicker2.SelectedItem;

if (is2Empty == true)
{
locationPicker2.IsEnabled = true;
}
drainxPicker.IsEnabled = false;
locationPicker2.IsEnabled = false;

}

void nxy1()
{
foreach (var location in list)
{
locationPicker1.Items.Add(location);
}

}


void nxy2()
{

foreach (var location in list)        
{
locationPicker2.Items.Add(location);
} 
}

void settingsaveButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
bool isNameEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameEntry.Text);

if (isNameEmpty == true)
{
DisplayAlert("Enter Name", "PLEASE", "OK");
}

else
{

Navigation.PushModalAsync(new HomePage());



//saving to Settings
Settings.n1LocationSettings = location1;
Settings.n2LocationSettings = location2;
Settings.NameSettings = username;
Settings.DrainquantitySettings = item;

drainxPicker.IsEnabled = false;
}

}

void entryNameHandle_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
{
username = nameEntry.Text;
}

void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
Settings.ClearAllData();
}
}
}
```

I expect that when i click on tabbed settings page, i go to the settings page with info entered populated. just like the button click it goes to settings page already populated with user entered.

Comment: generally, yes they should be the same, but without knowing more about what you're doing in SettingsPage its impossible to say for sure

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It should be the same. Can you please share the code in the SettingsPage?

Comment: settingsPage attached @Jack Hua - MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, tabbed settings page and pushed settings page is the same. They are all `new fresh settings page`.

From your code, we can see that you are setting the value of Picker by `Settings` plugin:

```
drainxPicker.SelectedItem = Settings.DrainquantitySettings;
locationPicker1.SelectedItem = Settings.n1LocationSettings;
locationPicker2.SelectedItem = Settings.n2LocationSettings;
```

So, whether the info entered will be populated or not when you go to the setting page is depending on the values in `Settings`.

For example:

If `Settings.DrainquantitySettings;` has value, then drainxPicker's info will be populated.

Check the `Values` in your `Setting` when you go to tabbed settings page and pushed settings page to find any difference.

Comment: im using xamarin.plugins.settings by montemagno, so I can only see value on "Settings" after I close the app then restart it again.  if i don't restart the app then "Settings" are "". is there an autoupdate on that plugin I use so that it will update it without the need of closing the app and remembering last selected item?

Comment: @hypnocool You can use [xamarin/essentials/preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android), easier and faster.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56907222/xamarin-how-to-convert-my-xamarin-plugins-settings-to-xamarin-preferences-essen

Comment: you are right if settings has value then it will populated. it seems that I'm saving from Settingspage to a variable.  it should be:    void entryNameHandle_Unfocused(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            // username = nameEntry.Text;
            Settings.NameSettings = nameEntry.Text;
        }

Comment: this statement doesn't clear the data right away.  I have to close app then re run. any advise how to clear data entered right away or force it with "" empty string first?                                                                                                           void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{   
Settings.ClearAllData();
}

Comment: You mean  Settings.ClearAllData(); does not work? Maybe you can  force it with "" empty string. I did not use Pulgin.Settings before.

Comment: Settings.ClearAllData() does work.  In the beginning, I was wondering why the picker wasn't clearing while the Settings data cleared.  The pickers only clears after closing the app then reopenning it.  It seems that I needed one more line of code to push the settings page to load again when i clicked on the CLEAR button.   void clearHandle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.ClearAllData();    
            Navigation.PushModalAsync(new SettingsPage());
        }

Comment: If you cleaned the Settings data. Next time you go to setting page, you will get the value from the Setting and it is empty. No need to go to setting page again.