# Xamarin, how to convert my Xamarin.plugins.settings to xamarin.preferences.essentials to save values entered?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Ive been using Montemagno's plugin for saving Settings but someone mentioned it's better to user preferences.essential.  There's not much tutorial on it.

I'm having problem the getting and setting the value and accessing it from another file from where I set it.

```cs
//Settings.cs
public static string NameSettings
{
    get
    {
        return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SettingsnameKey, SettingsDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SettingsnameKey, value);
    }
}

public static string DrainquantitySettings
{
    get
    {
        return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(SettingsdrainxKey, SettingsDefault);
    }
    set
    {
        AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(SettingsdrainxKey, value);
    }
}

//this is how i get it in another file
drainxPicker.SelectedItem = Settings.DrainquantitySettings;

nameEntry.Text = Settings.NameSettings;

//to set it
Settings.NameSettings = username;
Settings.DrainquantitySettings = item;


//to convert to preferences?
public static NameSettings
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(NameSettings), username);
    set => Preferences.Set(nameof(NameSettings), value);
}

//to use it??
nameEntry.Text = Preferences.Settings.NameSettings;

//to set it??
Preferences.Settings.NameSettings = username;
```

Comment: it's very unclear what you're trying to do.  You mention wanting to use the new Essentials Preferences plugin, but all of your code appears to be for the Settings plugin.  Please clarify what you're tying to do and what specific problem that you're having.

Comment: @Jason I wanted to know how to set it up using Essentials Preferences plugin.  Like syntax how to set it, how to get data, from it.  They said it's easier than the Montemagno plugin so im thinking of switching it.

Comment: Have you read the docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=ios

Comment: yes..scroll down on code...i added of what i think i understood... nameEntry.Text = Preferences.Settings.NameSettings;  is that how you use it?

Comment: there is no Settings property, just Get and Set.  You can add whatever sort of helper/wrapper you want to it.

Comment: //to use it??
nameEntry.Text = Preferences.Settings.NameSettings;

Comment: nameEntry.Text = Preferences.Get("Name",string.Empty);

Answer (score 1):

I just did this very thing

```cs
public static bool UploadOnlyOverWifi
{
    get => Preferences.Get(nameof(UploadOnlyOverWifi), false);
    set => Preferences.Set(nameof(UploadOnlyOverWifi), value);
}
```

Comment: so that's how you set it up, now how do you use it? If (UploadOnlyOverWifi == true) or If (Preferences.UploadOnlyOverWifi == true) –

Answer (score 0):

According to Jason's reply, you can use Preferences.Set() to save value ,and using Preferences.Get() to retrieve value from preference.

```
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry x:Name="entry1" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnsave"
            Clicked="Btnsave_Clicked"
            Text="Save" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btnget"
            Clicked="Btnget_Clicked"
            Text="Get" />
    </StackLayout>

private void Btnsave_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("key1", entry1.Text);
    }

    private void Btnget_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string value1 = Preferences.Get("key1","");
        DisplayAlert("Success", "Your Value is " + value1, "OK");
    }
```